# Random sample of rows from subset of an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sample

Is there a good way of getting a sample of rows from part of a dataframe?

If I just have data such as

```
gender <- c("F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F")
age    <- c(23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37)
```

then I can easily sample the ages of three of the Fs with

```
sample(age[gender == "F"], 3)
```

and get something like

```
[1] 31 35 29
```

but if I turn this data into a dataframe

```
mydf <- data.frame(gender, age)
```

I cannot use the obvious

```
sample(mydf[mydf$gender == "F", ], 3)
```

though I can concoct something convoluted with an absurd number of brackets like

```
mydf[sample((1:nrow(mydf))[mydf$gender == "F"], 3), ]
```

and get what I want which is something like

```
  gender age
7      F  35
4      F  29
1      F  23
```

Is there a better way that takes me less time to work out how to write?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your convoluted way is pretty much how to do it - I think all the answers will be variations on that theme.

For example, I like to generate the `mydf$gender=="F"` indices first:

```
idx <- which(mydf$gender=="F")
```

Then I sample from that:

```
mydf[ sample(idx,3), ]
```

So in one line (although, you reduce the absurd number of brackets and possibly make your code easier to understand by having multiple lines):

```
mydf[ sample( which(mydf$gender=='F'), 3 ), ]
```

While the "wheee I'm a hacker!" part of me prefers the one-liner, the sensible part of me says that even though the two-liner is two lines, it is much more understandable - it's just your choice.

Comment: 6 brackets (whether on one or two lines) is certainly better than 10.

Comment: I still can't believe there's no easy way to carry on such a funcamental statistical procedure in R. There's gotta be an app, I mean, a package for that.

Answer (score 9):

You say *I cannot use the obvious:*

```
sample(mydf[mydf$gender == "F", ], 3)
```

but you could write your own function for doing it:

```
sample.df <- function(df, n) df[sample(nrow(df), n), , drop = FALSE]
```

then run it on your subset selection:

```
sample.df(mydf[mydf$gender == "F", ], 3)
#   gender age
# 5      F  31
# 4      F  29
# 1      F  23
```

(Personally I find `sample.df(subset(mydf, gender == "F"), 3)` easier to read.)

Answer (score 2):

This is now simpler with the enhanced version of `sample` in my package:

```
library(devtools); install_github('kimisc', 'krlmlr')

library(kimisc)
sample.rows(subset(mydf, gender == "F"), 3)
```

See also this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16538269/946850) for more detail.