# Randomly sample a percentage of rows within a data frame

Tags: r, row, subset, random

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628152/random-sample-of-rows-from-subset-of-an-r-dataframe) question.

```
gender <- c("F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F")
age    <- c(23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37)
mydf <- data.frame(gender, age) 

mydf[ sample( which(mydf$gender=='F'), 3 ), ]
```

Instead of selecting a number of rows (3 in above case), how can I randomly select 20% of rows with "F"? So of the five rows with "F", how do I randomly sample 20% of those rows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this:

```
mydf[ sample( which(mydf$gender=='F'), round(0.2*length(which(mydf$gender=='F')))), ]
```

Where 0.2 is your 20% and `length(which(mydf$gender=='F'))` is the total number of rows with `F`

Comment: +1, but do mind that 20% can be something other than an integer, so using round would be needed.

Comment: good point, thanks, I've added that in. By the way, you're missing a comma and close square bracket in your answer

Answer (score 23):

You can use `sample_frac()` function in `dplyr` package.

e.g. 
If you want to sample 20 % within each group:

```
mydf %>% sample_frac(.2)
```

If you want to sample 20 % within each gender group:

```
mydf %>% group_by(gender) %>% sample_frac(.2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Self-promotion alert. I wrote a function that allows convenient stratified sampling, and I've included an option to subset levels from the grouping variables before sampling.

The function is called `stratified` and can be used in the following ways:

```
set.seed(1)
# Proportional sample
stratified(mydf, group="gender", size=.2, select=list(gender = "F"))
#   gender age
# 4      F  29
# Fixed-size sampling
stratified(mydf, group="gender", size=2, select=list(gender = "F"))
#   gender age
# 4      F  29
# 5      F  31
```

You can specify multiple groups (for example if your data frame included a "state" variable and you wanted to group by "state" and "gender" you would specify `group = c("state", "gender")`). You can also specify multiple "select" arguments (for example, if you wanted only female respondents from California and Texas, and your "state" variable used two-letter state abbreviations, you could specify `select = list(gender = "F", state = c("CA", "TX"))`).

The function itself can be found [here](https://github.com/mrdwab/mrdwabmisc/blob/master/R/stratified.R) or you can download and install the package (which gives you convenient access to the help pages and examples) by  using `install_github` from the "devtools" package as follows:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("mrdwabmisc", "mrdwab")
```

Comment: Hi the url link seems to be dead

Answer (score 2):

To sample 20%, you can use this to get the sample size:

```
n = round(0.2 * nrow(mydf[mydf$gender == "F",]))
```

Comment: Yeah, I was able to do that but this is a file that's automated and run every hour so I can't really go in and adjust the values w/o writing another function w/ an if else statement. Figured there'd be a simpler approach

Comment: This is exactly the answer to your question, if your question is different, please edit in more details.

Comment: Anyone care to comment on the downvote? This answer exactly answers the question.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, I am not sure if this is the answer to this question, seems this only return the number of rows not the actual data, Could you please advise, seems Ben's answer returns the expected result