# sample percentage of rows in dataframe for 1000 times with identificaton for each sampling

Tags: r, for-loop, random

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030910/randomly-sample-a-percentage-of-rows-within-a-data-frame) question.

```
gender <- c("F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F")
age    <- c(23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37)
mydf <- data.frame(gender, age)

mydf[sample(nrow(mydf), round(0.25*nrow(mydf))),]
```

But I want this random sampling for 1000 times with identification number.

For example, from these 1000 random sample I want to call the 5th or 70th sample. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `replicate` to sample it 1000 times to store it in a `list`

```
lst <- replicate(1000, mydf[sample(nrow(mydf), round(0.25*nrow(mydf))),] , simplify = FALSE)
```

Then, get the 5th and 70th `list` element by subsetting with index

```
lst[c(5, 70)]
```