# Sample n random draw within group with different nrows

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I draw `n` rows from a group where each group has a different number of rows?

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(80), nrow=40))
df$color <-  rep(c("blue", "red", "yellow", "pink"), each=10)
```

I've tried,

```
library(dplyr)
outdat <- df %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  sample_n(nrow(.), replace = TRUE)
outdat
```

but this returns a data.frame where `nrow(.)` are nrows from df and not the subset.

[This SO post is close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831711/sample-n-random-rows-per-group-in-a-dataframe), but defines a specific number of row draws. I need it to be specific to group within dplyr.

Comment: It's not clear to me how many rows you want to sample from each group, how this relates to the original number of rows per group.

Comment: how many rows you want to sample from your `df`? if you want 10 rows, you can use `sample_n(df, 10)`

Comment: @Snubian I want to sample the number of rows from the grouped data.

Comment: @mt1022 I Tried `n()` and it can't be used directly. `Error: This function should not be called directly`

Comment: @myincas I want to sample the number of rows defined in each group, so I don't want to specify exact samples.

Comment: @RonakShah Think of a subset of data and the number of rows in that subset. I need it defined by each group because they vary across groups.

Comment: @RonakShah The output data should have the same dimensions as the original data, but the observations may be different because of sampling with replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another workaround, use `sample_frac`:

```
outdat <- df %>%
    group_by(color) %>%
    sample_frac(1, replace = TRUE)
outdat
# # A tibble: 40 x 3
# # Groups:   color [4]
#             X1          X2 color
#          <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>
#  1  0.69256186  0.97180252  blue
#  2  1.54384827 -0.20268802  blue
#  3 -1.20068240 -0.45402013  blue
#  4  2.63407877 -0.31644247  blue
#  5  1.20716737 -0.91380874  blue
#  6  0.01067475  1.02004679  blue
#  7  0.01067475  1.02004679  blue
#  8  1.79732108 -0.04072946  blue
#  9  0.01067475  1.02004679  blue
# 10  1.79732108 -0.04072946  blue
# # ... with 30 more rows
```

Additionally, use `outdat %>% ungroup()` to remove grouping.

Comment: This is more what I'm looking for because it can handle multiple groups.  Thanks!

Comment: I like this. This solution does not need to load the `purrr` package as my post does. I think it is the better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `slice` and `sample.int`.
Reusing data from www:

```
outdat <- df %>% 
group_by(color) %>% 
slice(sample.int(n(),replace=T))
outdat

            X1          X2  color
1   1.71506499 -1.12310858   blue
2   0.07050839  2.16895597   blue
3   0.46091621 -0.40288484   blue
4   0.07050839  2.16895597   blue
5   0.07050839  2.16895597   blue
6   1.71506499 -1.12310858   blue
7  -1.26506123 -0.46665535   blue
8   1.55870831 -1.26539635   blue
9   0.12928774  1.20796200   blue
10  1.55870831 -1.26539635   blue
11  0.55391765 -0.28477301   pink
12 -0.29507148 -2.30916888   pink
13 -0.30596266  0.18130348   pink
14 -0.06191171 -1.22071771   pink
15  0.55391765 -0.28477301   pink
16  0.55391765 -0.28477301   pink
17  0.87813349 -0.70920076   pink
18  0.68864025  1.02557137   pink
19 -0.30596266  0.18130348   pink
20  0.68864025  1.02557137   pink
21  0.70135590  0.12385424    red
22  0.11068272  1.36860228    red
23 -1.96661716  0.58461375    red
24  0.40077145 -0.04287046    red
25  1.78691314  1.51647060    red
26 -0.55584113 -0.22577099    red
27  0.40077145 -0.04287046    red
28  1.78691314  1.51647060    red
29 -0.47279141  0.21594157    red
30 -0.47279141  0.21594157    red
31 -1.02600445 -0.33320738 yellow
32 -0.72889123 -1.01857538 yellow
33  1.25381492  2.05008469 yellow
34  0.83778704  0.44820978 yellow
35  1.25381492  2.05008469 yellow
36 -0.62503927 -1.07179123 yellow
37 -0.62503927 -1.07179123 yellow
38  0.83778704  0.44820978 yellow
39 -0.21797491 -0.50232345 yellow
40 -1.68669331  0.30352864 yellow
```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround using the `purrr` pakcage. It seems like the `sample_n` function cannot take `n()` as the size argument, probably because that argument does not take vectorized input. However, if we split the data frame by `color` as group, we can apply the `sample_n` with `nrow()` for each group.

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Create example data frame
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(80), nrow=40))
df$color <-  rep(c("blue", "red", "yellow", "pink"), each=10)

# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

outdat <- df %>%
  # Split the data frame by color
  split(.$color) %>%
  # Apply the sample_n function to all data frames
  map_dfr(~sample_n(., size = nrow(.), replace = TRUE))

outdat
#             X1          X2  color
# 1   1.71506499 -1.12310858   blue
# 2   0.07050839  2.16895597   blue
# 3   0.46091621 -0.40288484   blue
# 4   0.07050839  2.16895597   blue
# 5   0.07050839  2.16895597   blue
# 6   1.71506499 -1.12310858   blue
# 7  -1.26506123 -0.46665535   blue
# 8   1.55870831 -1.26539635   blue
# 9   0.12928774  1.20796200   blue
# 10  1.55870831 -1.26539635   blue
# 11  0.55391765 -0.28477301   pink
# 12 -0.29507148 -2.30916888   pink
# 13 -0.30596266  0.18130348   pink
# 14 -0.06191171 -1.22071771   pink
# 15  0.55391765 -0.28477301   pink
# 16  0.55391765 -0.28477301   pink
# 17  0.87813349 -0.70920076   pink
# 18  0.68864025  1.02557137   pink
# 19 -0.30596266  0.18130348   pink
# 20  0.68864025  1.02557137   pink
# 21  0.70135590  0.12385424    red
# 22  0.11068272  1.36860228    red
# 23 -1.96661716  0.58461375    red
# 24  0.40077145 -0.04287046    red
# 25  1.78691314  1.51647060    red
# 26 -0.55584113 -0.22577099    red
# 27  0.40077145 -0.04287046    red
# 28  1.78691314  1.51647060    red
# 29 -0.47279141  0.21594157    red
# 30 -0.47279141  0.21594157    red
# 31 -1.02600445 -0.33320738 yellow
# 32 -0.72889123 -1.01857538 yellow
# 33  1.25381492  2.05008469 yellow
# 34  0.83778704  0.44820978 yellow
# 35  1.25381492  2.05008469 yellow
# 36 -0.62503927 -1.07179123 yellow
# 37 -0.62503927 -1.07179123 yellow
# 38  0.83778704  0.44820978 yellow
# 39 -0.21797491 -0.50232345 yellow
# 40 -1.68669331  0.30352864 yellow
```

Comment: That's easy enough. Thanks! It is surprising to me `dplyr` can't handle this. Is there any way to incorporate multiple factors?

Comment: Thanks. I feel the same. My first thought to this task is also put `n()` to the `size` argument, but it just returns `Error: This function should not be called directly`.