# Randomly assigning values of an existing variable to new rows in a data frame in R within an ID

Tags: r

Well, this is embarrassing.

I'm trying to do something fairly straightforward: conduct a robustness check by seeing if the correlation between `x` and `y` is removed if the values for `x` are "mismatched" with `y`. I'm trying to do this by creating a third variable `z` which "mixes up" the existing values of 'x' at random.  While this is a similar question to the [one previously answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273313/random-rows-in-dataframe-in-r), my data are in long form **so I need to randomize WITHIN an `id` variable.**

For example, my dataset might be:

```
x    y    id
1    4    1
1    5    1
2    8    1
2    8    1
3    12   1
3    11   1
4    16   1
4    15   1
1    4    2
1    5    2
2    8    2
2    8    2
3    12   2
3    11   2
4    16   2
4    15   2
```

What I'd like to do is to create a new variable `z` which essentially "mixes up" the values of `x` (but is based on the actual values of `x`, NOT a random variable within a certain range):

```
x    y    id   z
1    4    1    2
1    5    1    3
2    8    1    1
2    8    1    4
3    12   1    4
3    11   1    3
4    16   1    2
4    15   1    1
1    4    2    1
1    5    2    1
2    8    2    3
2    8    2    3
3    12   2    4
3    11   2    4
4    16   2    2
4    15   2    2
```

How on earth do I do this? I started out thinking it was a simple task, but then got very very confused.

**SUPER-DUPER-BONUS-QUESTION:**

Finally, as the careful reader will note, the data are in long form (each `id` has 8 rows) but they are also grouped by `x` (which has 4 values per `id`). In other words, each person has 8 observed outcomes of `y`, but only 4 predictors of `x`.  **In a perfect world, I'd be able to create a function where `z` mixed up values of `x` within `id` -- and but never assigned the same value of `x` to `z`.**

In other words, if `x=1`, then `z=2,3, or 4` but NOT `1`.  It is a subtle difference, but a potentially meaningful one!

```
x    y    id   z
1    4    1    2
1    5    1    3
2    8    1    1
2    8    1    4
3    12   1    4
3    11   1    2
4    16   1    3
4    15   1    1
1    4    2    3
1    5    2    3
2    8    2    1
2    8    2    1
3    12   2    4
3    11   2    4
4    16   2    2
4    15   2    2
```

Comment: Try `data$z<-sample(data$x)`

Comment: Ah, yes. So "embarrassing" WAS the right adjective. Thanks @Frank and @mrip!

Comment: @Frank and @mrip: New question...how would I do this WITHIN values of another variable, i.e. there was a set of x values for a person with `id`?  (I've modified the question above!)

Comment: You sure you don't want to make a new question? I would convert the data to a `data.table` (requiring a package of the same name), and then do `DT[,z:=sample(x),by=id]`, but I won't post that here in case you want to make a new question.

Comment: or `plyr::ddply(data,"id",transform,z=sample(x))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random rows in dataframe in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273313/random-rows-in-dataframe-in-r)

Comment: Thanks everyone! To make things more clear for future readers, I am going to reframe my question so that it more clearly leads to the answer provided (and isn't a duplicate!). I also added an extension to this question (regarding more complicated logic), if anyone has thoughts :)

Comment: @Frank-My Q actually became more complicated; in addition to sampling within ID, I need to make it so that the values of z != x (if x=1, then z=2,3, or 4). Do you have any ideas for an elegant `data.table` solution?

Comment: @roody: Oops, that dash after my name on your last comment meant that I didn't get pinged. I guess you know, but just to clarify: if you have a new super-duper extension, it's probably best (for you, us, future visitors, the site) to write a new question elsewhere and leave the first alone... :) But anyway, I think there may be a way to do what you're looking for with `sample` and `combn` (though I don't have much experience with the latter).

Answer (score 1):

#### Update (actually, entirely new answer) for a new question

Nothing came to my mind immediately, so I thought I should just propose a `while`-based solution. This function basically checks whether any of the results of `sample` are the same as the value of the input vector. If yes, run `sample` and try again....

```
Shuffled <- function(inVec) {
  Res <- vector()
  while ( TRUE ) {
    Res <- sample(inVec)
    if ( !any(Res == inVec) ) { break }
  }
  Res
}

set.seed(1)
mydf$z <- ave(mydf$x, mydf$id, FUN = Shuffled)

mydf
#    x  y id z
# 1  1  4  1 2
# 2  1  5  1 4
# 3  2  8  1 4
# 4  2  8  1 3
# 5  3 12  1 2
# 6  3 11  1 1
# 7  4 16  1 3
# 8  4 15  1 1
# 9  1  4  2 2
# 10 1  5  2 2
# 11 2  8  2 3
# 12 2  8  2 4
# 13 3 12  2 4
# 14 3 11  2 1
# 15 4 16  2 1
# 16 4 15  2 3

any(mydf$x == mydf$z)
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Hi @Ananda - thanks for your answer! To resolve the duplication concern, I made my question more specific. I also added an extension of the logic to the question, if you have any thoughts. (Also, is this kind of editing bad etiquette? I'm happy to start a new question if so).

Comment: @roody, within a certain time-frame, based on comments, I don't feel it's bad etiquette to edit your question, though your current question is *dramatically* different from your first one.

Comment: @roody, see my updated answer. I think it captures what you were looking for.

Comment: hi @Ananda! I follow conceptually, but when I try to run the function my computer is freezing.  Is the following the correct way to apply your function using data.table? `mydf[, eval(Shuffled(c('x','id'))),]`?

Comment: @roody, No. That is not the correct way for using "data.table". First your object has to be a `data.table`. (`library(data.table); DT <- data.table(mydf)`). Next, you have to use `:=` to create your new column: (`DT[, z := Shuffled(x), by = id]; DT`).

Comment: Hi @Ananda Mahto - I've tried both using base R and data.table, but my R is timing out and doesn't actually produce a new variable. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?