# Extracting a random sample of rows in a data.frame with a nested conditional

Tags: r, random

This question builds from the SO post  [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273313/random-rows-in-dataframe-in-r) and uses code that was modified from a post on the R-help mailing list which can be [seen here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-February/125860.html)

I am trying to extract a random sample of rows in a data frame but with a conditional.  Using the R `iris` data which looks like:

```
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

To take a simple random sample, the code below works fine to take a sample of 2 rows.

```
iris[sample(nrow(iris), 2), ]
```

However I am unsure how to condition the Species field.  For example how to take the random sample as indicated above but only when `Species != “setosa”`

There are three categories of `iris$Species`

```
> summary(iris$Species)
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
        50         50         50
```

I am unsure how to correctly nest conditionals.  One of my earlier attempts is below with the obviously incorrect results included….

```
> iris[sample(nrow(iris)[iris$Species != "setosa"], 2), ]
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
NA             NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
NA.1           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
```

Thanks

Comment: `iris[ sample( which( iris$Species != "setosa" ) , 2 ) , ]`

Comment: @SimonO101 Post as an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd use `which` to get the vector of rows numbers from which you can `sample` given your condition....

```
iris[ sample( which( iris$Species != "setosa" ) , 2 ) , ]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#59           6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
#133          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.2  virginica
```

Comment: Slick. Thanks, I too often forget about which().

Comment: @simon-ohanlon How can I apply this condition: take random sample with replacement but probabilities should be 80% versicolor and 20% virginica

Comment: How can I make a train set with, say n, random row with a certain condition. For example, 10 random rows that stisfy iris$Species == "setosa", 10 random rows  that stisfy iris$Species == "versicolor" and 10 random rows that stisfy iris$Species == "virginica"?

Comment: @MehdiAbbassi Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23193184/1478381 `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(sample_n(.,10))`

Comment: Hi @SimonO'Hanlon. This was helpful. Can you show how to add two/multiple conditions / conditions from two or more columns instead of one?

Answer (score 12):

With dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(12)
filter(iris, Species != "setosa") %>% sample_n(., 2)
```

Output:

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
7           6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor
81          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica
```

Answer (score 4):

It'd be cleaner to not do it in one line, but

```
iris[iris$Species != "setosa",][sample(nrow(iris[iris$Species != "setosa",]), 2), ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Clean and simple data table approach:

```
require(data.table)
iris <- data.table(iris)
cond <- iris[Species!= 'setosa', which = T]
iris[sample(cond, 2)]
```