# Sample rows of subgroups with different sample size for each group with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, tidyverse

I have seen the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255366/sample-rows-of-subgroups-from-dataframe-with-dplyr) question but I have `K` groups, each of them with `n[k]` elements, and I want to draw for example `floor(n[k] * p)` samples from each of these groups.

I was thinking something like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(my_group) %>%
  mutate(
    n_samples = floor(n() / 2)
  ) %>%
  sample_n(n_samples)
```

But that doesn't work because the argument for `sample_n` should be the same for every group.

I prefer solutions using `dplyr` or at least following the `tidyverse` convention.

Comment: are you looking for the [`sample_frac`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/sample.html) function?

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed for my case. I couldn't accept that as an answer though because in the general case the number of samples can be different from a fraction of the group size.