# How to resample the rows by group with the same seed in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to do a resampling on a dataset by group (`name` column). For example:

```
names <- c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 3)) 
test <- tibble(name = names, number = rep(c(1:3), 3))
test
  name number
  <chr> <int>
1 a         1
2 a         2
3 a         3
4 b         1
5 b         2
6 b         3
7 c         1
8 c         2
9 c         3
```

I know there is a `slice_sample` in tidyverse, but I notice it's not able to set seed to make each group have the same resampled results (`number`). I wonder how I could resample rows in each `name` group **with replacement** and each group can also have the same results (1-2-2), like below expected output?

```
  name number
1 a         1
2 a         2
3 a         2
4 b         1
5 b         2
6 b         2
7 c         1
8 c         2
9 c         2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are the groups in your real data as identical as your example (i.e. each has the same number of rows etc)? Do you just want to sample so that same row numbers are selected for each group?  Maybe something like (hard coded just as an example) `rs <- sample(3, replace = TRUE); test %>% slice(rs, .by = name)` would suffice.

Comment: @ritchie-sacramento yeah, it's not identical with the real data, but each group will have the same number of rows with the same order. In other words, the same row index of grouped data should be selected for each group. Can you try to post an answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sample the same row indices per group you can first generate the indices and then pass these to `slice()`. It may be unnecessary, but we can wrap it up in a function that checks that the groups are of equal size.

```
library(dplyr)

slice_same_idx <- function(data, group = group) {
  n <- data %>%
    group_by({{group}}) %>%
    group_size()
  
  stopifnot("Unequal group sizes" = n_distinct(n) == 1)
  
  idx <- sample(n[1], replace = TRUE)
  
  data %>%
    slice(idx, .by = {{group}})
}

test %>%
  slice_same_idx(name)

# A tibble: 9 × 2
  name  number
  <chr>  <int>
1 a          3
2 a          1
3 a          1
4 b          3
5 b          1
6 b          1
7 c          3
8 c          1
9 c          1
```

Comment: just one follow-up question, assume the number of rows is the same for each group, but does the order of rows matter in your approach?

Comment: No, each row has equal probability of being selected regardless of order.