# Scale curves so that they are all on the same axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with water levels. However, each water level is represented in mAOD (i.e. meters above sea level). Because of the positioning of each dip well this means the scale of the data is quite spread out. Is there an easy way to standardise the scale so they are all comparable. i.e. each curves starts at 0 and then fluctates from that point.

#### What my data currently looks like

each line represents one of the dipwells.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
dataPlot <- dfDay %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=only_date, y=mAOD, colour=loc, fill=mere)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_classic()

plot(dataPlot)
```

#### UPDATED Example Data

```
        structure(list(loc = c("B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", 
"B2", "B2", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", 
"B3"), only_date = structure(c(18892, 18569, 19364, 19413, 18401, 
18993, 19105, 19024, 18884, 18866, 18658, 19001, 19179, 18343, 
18338, 18487, 18689, 18608, 18410, 19259, 18885, 18997, 19378, 
19399, 18856, 18704, 18950, 18985, 19312, 19195), class = "Date"), 
    mAOD = c(76.4009708333333, 76.4595041666667, 76.4425658333333, 
    76.434795, 76.4279583333333, 76.4543291666667, 76.4517416666667, 
    76.4566666666667, 76.4300916666667, 76.41275, 75.7512166666667, 
    75.7413333333333, 75.7299333333333, 75.745425, 75.7511041666667, 
    75.739375, 75.7554875, 75.7423666666667, 75.7269583333333, 
    75.6779708333333, 74.5823541666667, 74.6553875, 74.7552704166667, 
    74.74291375, 74.5447083333333, 74.6244708333333, 74.5701541666667, 
    74.6534125, 74.7196166666667, 74.3292041666667), groundLevel = c(76.47, 
    76.47, 76.47, 76.47, 76.47, 76.47, 76.47, 76.47, 76.47, 76.47, 
    75.749, 75.749, 75.749, 75.749, 75.749, 75.749, 75.749, 75.749, 
    75.749, 75.749, 74.729, 74.729, 74.729, 74.729, 74.729, 74.729, 
    74.729, 74.729, 74.729, 74.729), rel_ground = c(-0.0690291666666673, 
    -0.0104958333333342, -0.0274341666666687, -0.0352050000000019, 
    -0.0420416666666655, -0.0156708333333331, -0.0182583333333331, 
    -0.0133333333333325, -0.0399083333333348, -0.057250000000001, 
    0.00221666666667394, -0.00766666666666005, -0.0190666666666578, 
    -0.00357499999999256, 0.00210416666667553, -0.00962499999999267, 
    0.00648750000000871, -0.00663333333332498, -0.0220416666666588, 
    -0.0710291666666591, -0.146645833333328, -0.0736124999999953, 
    0.0262704166666706, 0.0139137500000034, -0.184291666666664, 
    -0.104529166666662, -0.158845833333329, -0.0755874999999957, 
    -0.00938333333332804, -0.399795833333329), siteTemp = c(13.23875, 
    10.5433333333333, 8.22045833333333, 7.974125, 9.68541666666667, 
    8.85833333333333, 9.6625, 7.25166666666667, 13.60125, 13.40375, 
    6.76, 7.89708333333333, 10.9870833333333, 8.06541666666667, 
    8.22541666666667, 11.7675, 7.32291666666667, 8.53583333333333, 
    10.0054166666667, 12.0283333333333, 13.3191666666667, 7.84541666666667, 
    4.90841666666667, 4.7765, 13.20375, 5.71083333333333, 9.74416666666667, 
    6.91041666666667, 10.2575, 12.5633333333333), baroTemp = c(14.2945833333333, 
    6.2275, 9.48570833333333, 3.64475, 16.2891666666667, 12.4508333333333, 
    11.3541666666667, 9.705, 15.1158333333333, 13.82625, 0.857083333333333, 
    3.945, 16.6854166666667, 5.85416666666667, 11.6070833333333, 
    22.1295833333333, 3.53916666666667, 6.82, 18.8345833333333, 
    11.9033333333333, 14.9720833333333, 3.43416666666667, -1.21591666666667, 
    8.36458333333333, 14.7433333333333, 7.04583333333333, 11.6491666666667, 
    5.64458333333333, 6.84958333333333, 15.7204166666667), spi = c(0.30077434, 
    -0.23930748, NaN, NaN, -2.6496189, -0.5860415, 0.33465025, 
    1.0451335, 0.30077434, -0.43167603, 1.8315325, -0.5860415, 
    -0.9746731, 1.3363327, 1.3363327, 1.6203027, 1.5484929, 0.9624635, 
    -2.6496189, -0.70793974, 0.30077434, -0.5860415, NaN, NaN, 
    -0.43167603, 1.5484929, -0.3823883, 0.35713777, 1.0100443, 
    -0.9746731), beaverEvent = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("BB", 
    "AB", "D"), class = "factor"), mere = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("chapel", 
    "hatch", "coleCrose", "crose"), class = "factor"), damEvent = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("1", 
    "2", "3"), class = "factor"), ind = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("ground", 
    "surface"), class = "factor"), mAODscale = c(0.205100240746303, 
    0.223349733604873, 0.218068708664052, 0.21564592220468, 0.213514389752922, 
    0.221736274740243, 0.220929545307926, 0.22246505929987, 0.214179519333188, 
    0.208772743331098, 0.00252021755022926, -0.000561203083351044, 
    -0.00411548927790027, 0.000714494666301607, 0.00248514235751982, 
    -0.00117177125273694, 0.00385177579197538, -0.000239030942907465, 
    -0.00504303326287931, -0.0203163310660017, -0.361907137456628, 
    -0.339136841982182, -0.307995397089215, -0.31184795232992, 
    -0.37364433620216, -0.348776024571206, -0.365710847243781, 
    -0.339752606476414, -0.319111505107548, -0.440834115540011
    ), sample = structure(c(2L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), groups = structure(list(
    loc = c("B1", "B2", "B3"), .rows = structure(list(1:10, 11:20, 
        21:30), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: subtract the first value of each line from all values of theat line?

Comment: Maybe scale between 2 numbers, see relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5468280/680068

Comment: Could you please share more data? Now we can only show you 1 line.

Comment: @Quienten Theres 600,000 rows. I normally just use dput(head(df)). How can I dput to show various locations?

Comment: Yes, we need more than 1 location, so we can test with multiple lines. 5-10 rows per location, maybe 3 locations. See this post on how to get sample n rows per group: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21255366/680068

Comment: @Quienten I've updated the example data

Comment: Are you sure that you want to fluctuate all curves around the *first* value? Should they not be shifted such that zero is the *mean* value per waterbody?

Comment: @cdalitz I'm just trying to explore the options. That sounds like a good idea. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @melanie-baker "Do you know how to do that?" If your data is stored in a data.frame with each waterbody one column, you can center each column around its mean with the builtin function `scale(df, canter=T, scale=F)`. To do it by hand, you can use `colMeans` or `rowMeans` and subtract it from each col or row with `apply`, `sweep`, or use builtin matrix vector arithemetic, e.g. `t(t(A)A - colMeans(A))`.

Answer (score 1):

You provided grouped data so keep that in mind. As @Wimpel already suggested, you could extract the `first` value of each line like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dfDay %>%
  mutate(mAOD_ref = mAOD - first(mAOD)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=only_date, y=mAOD_ref, colour=loc, fill=mere)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_classic()
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>