# Selected randomly-sized, random subsets of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989355/extracting-a-random-sample-of-rows-in-a-data-frame-with-a-nested-conditional) question on extracting a random subset of rows.

My data look like:

```
scenario   urban_areas_simple       place      population
North       Primary Urban Areas     Leeds      700,000
South       Primary Urban Areas     London     9,000,000
Scotland    Rural                   Shetland   22,000
...         ...                     ...
```

Using dplyr I have the following code, which works, and randomly selected 4 rows, based on conditions in my `scenario` and `urban_areas_simple` columns:

```
filter(lads, 
    scenario == "north" & urban_areas_simple == "Primary Urban Areas") %>% 
    sample_n(4)
```

However, I also want to randomised the number of rows selected, as here I've only arbitrarily selected 4 as an example.

How would I randomly select rows meeting these conditions, for subsets of a random size?

NB: there may only be between 10-50 rows meeting each condition.

Comment: How about `sample_frac(runif(1))`

Comment: This didn't work Robin?

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge what exactly happens when you attempt Robin's solution? It works fine for me.

Comment: Actually, that was my mistake, it's now working with Robin's solution. Do you want to post a proper answer @RobinGertenbach?

Comment: Done. I didn't think it was worth adding to Roman's answer but forgot about the grouping benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filter(lads, 
  scenario == "north" & urban_areas_simple == "Primary Urban Areas") %>% 
  sample_frac(runif(1))
```

does just that.

The value is guaranteed to be returnable and it can handle stratified sampling from a grouped dataframe with unequal group sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 4, you can use `sample(1:100, size = 1)`. This will pick a random number between 1 and 100. If you want to make the process reproducible, stick a `set.seed(x)` before you start using any function which depends on a random seed. `x` is any integer.

Comment: This worked and yes, I've already set the seed, I just forgot to put it in the question. Is there anyway to avoid/catch/handle the error when the random number is larger than the number of observations in the data?

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge, that's why Robin's comment is quite nice. You could use `mtcars %>% sample_n(sample(1:nrow(.), 1))`, but it won't deal with grouped data.frames correctly.

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge you can use `tryCatch`. It may not be the most appropriate solution in this case, but it's very versatile. You could generate the vector of possible values with `1:nrow(x)`.