# How do I remove a certain number of cases from subset in R (I looked at other answers)?

Tags: r

So what I did was make a partition of 40%-60%. The 40% worked, but not the 60%.

```
> dim(clean_reg)
[1] 497  23
> partition = sample(x = 1:497, size = .4*497, replace=F)
> dog = clean_reg[partition, ]
> cat = clean_reg[!partition, ]
> dim(dog)
[1] 198  23
> dim(cat)
[1]  0 23
```

Why didn't the remaining 60% go into cat? Doesn't ! sufficiently do that?

Comment: See this question from  1 hour ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881622/how-to-write-the-remaining-data-frame-in-r-after-randomly-subseting-the-data

Answer (score 2):

`cat = clean_reg[-partition, ]` instead of `cat = clean_reg[!partition, ]`