# Error in sample(1:17260(E), 20) : attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r

It's possibly a very stupid question, but I'm getting an error message for this very simple piece of code in R:

```
  S20_1 = E[sample(1:17260(E), 20),]
```

The error message is:

> Error in sample(1:17260(E), 20) : attempt to apply non-function

`E` is a data frame with 17260 rows. The code is based on the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273313/random-rows-in-dataframe-in-r).

Comment: from the link you posted: `E[sample(nrow(E), 20), ]`

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what is wrong. Try to change the line into this:

```
S20_1 = E[sample(nrow(E), 20),]
```

or, since you already know the size of `E`

```
S20_1 = E[sample(1:17260, 20),]
```

though I would recommend the first method of course.

Hope this helps.