# Sample k rows from data frame and create identifier for which rows are selected in R

Tags: r, random, sample

My question relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273313/random-rows-in-dataframe-in-r) famous question. I want to select rows from a data frame

```
k=3
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
selected.rows = df[sample(nrow(df), k), ]
```

But instead of a new data.frame with `k` rows, I want a column vector in `df` indicating which rows are selected. I obviously cannot use

`sample(c(0,1),nrow(df),TRUE)`

Because then `k` cannot be specified. But something along these lines should give a solution.

Comment: what about `sample(c(rep(1, k), rep(0, nrow(df)-k)), FALSE)` ?

Comment: You could try something along the lines of `df$select <- 1:nrow(df) %in% sample(nrow(df), k)`

Comment: Ah perfect solutions both. @Heroka Just had the same thought (but that's easy to say now).