# In R, how do I change the values for a specific column in a random set of rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I've been reading another question about how to randomly subset rows of a dataframe, but I'm trouble figuring out how to change the values of a particular column in the dataframe for a random subset of the rows.

from [Sample random rows in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273313/random-rows-in-dataframe-in-r) :

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10)) 
df[sample(nrow(df), 3), ]
```

How do I replace randomly selected rows of the X1 column with 0's, for instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to select the column before setting the new value.

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10)) 
df[sample(nrow(df), 3), 'X1'] <- 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
df = data.table(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
df[sample(.N,3), V1 := 0]
```

Except for that the default colnames would be changed to 'V1''V2'...

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this!