# Subset by column criteria AND randomly sample rows of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

@gented's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273313/sample-random-rows-in-dataframe/16538269#16538269) demonstrates how to randomly select a subset of rows from a `data.table`.

What if I wanted to select all rows in a `data.table` for which the values in a certain column meet a specific condition, AND ADDITIONALLY select a random subset of rows from the `data.table` for which the values in the same column meet a different condition?

Say, for example, that I wanted a random sample of 5 rows from the `mtcars` `data.table` for which `cyl == 6`, *and* all rows for which `cyl == 8`.

Is this achievable in a better way than:

```
rbind(
    mtcars[ cyl == 8 ],
    mtcars[ cyl == 6 ][ sample(.N, 5) ]
)
```

That is, can I subset the `data.table` in a single set of `[]`'s so that I could also, for example, apply a function within that call (in the `lapply(.SD, function)` format)?

This obviously does not achieve the desired result, but is similar to the syntax I'm looking for:

```
mtcars[ 
    cyl == 8 | ( cyl == 6 & sample( .N, 5 ) ), 
    lapply(.SD, generic_funciton), 
    .SDcols = (specific_cols) 
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that, I would utilize the `.I` special symbol as follows:

```
DT <- as.data.table(mtcars)

DT[c(DT[, .I[cyl == 8]], sample(DT[, .I[cyl == 6]], 5))]
```

Now you can do some computations:

```
set.seed(2019)
DT[c(DT[, .I[cyl == 8]], sample(DT[, .I[cyl == 6]], 5))
   , lapply(.SD, mean)
   , by = am
   , .SDcols = 3:5]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    am   disp       hp     drat
> 1:  0 325.64 179.0667 3.224667
> 2:  1 243.00 204.7500 3.890000
> ```

---

If you want to reuse that index vector at a later moment, you can store it beforehand:

```
idx <- c(DT[, .I[cyl == 8]], sample(DT[, .I[cyl == 6]], 5))

DT[idx, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = 3:5]
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as `i` ends up with something that can be used to select rows,
you can put any valid expression there,
which technically means you can write:

```
DT[c(sample(which(cyl == 6), 5L), which(cyl == 8))]
```

But that probably won't benefit from [optimizations](https://rdrr.io/github/Rdatatable/data.table/man/datatable-optimize.html).

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16574176/5793905)
(and [secondary indices](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html)),
I would think something like this would be a lot faster:

```
sample_if <- function(condition, values, n) {
  if (condition)
    sample(values, n)
  else
    values
}

some_fun <- function(.SD) {
  .SD
}

DT[DT[.(c(6, 8)), sample_if(.BY$cyl == 6, .I, 5L), by = "cyl", on = "cyl"]$V1,
   some_fun(.SD),
   .SDcols = c("cyl", "mpg")]
    cyl  mpg
 1:   6 19.7
 2:   6 19.2
 3:   6 21.4
 4:   6 21.0
 5:   6 18.1
 6:   8 18.7
 7:   8 14.3
 8:   8 16.4
 9:   8 17.3
10:   8 15.2
11:   8 10.4
12:   8 10.4
13:   8 14.7
14:   8 15.5
15:   8 15.2
16:   8 13.3
17:   8 19.2
18:   8 15.8
19:   8 15.0
```